# How to encoding in Spark dataframe while reading xml through sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")

Tags: dataframe, character-encoding

I have an XML file with `encoding="UTF-8"` which contains a few French letters inside an element.

Example `<Name>Áudio</Name>;`

I'm unable to read the XML through

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
               .option("rowTag", "root_Tag")
               .load("file:/Users/test.xml");
```

It shows "_corrupt_record" but If I removed the French character, it works perfectly.

I belive that issue is because of the encoding. How can I do encoding in `sqlContext` while reading XML?

I also tested with `.option("charset","UTF-8")` in by reading but it does not work. Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: I have solved my issue by applying UTF8 as system level in the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8. It works perfectly. Now, I able to read the entire xml in my spark dataframe

Comment: I had the same issue with cyrillic characters like 'у' (utf 0x443) and setting up the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable worked. Thanks @Deepan

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the option with lowercase (utf-8)